# AAD Login throws NotImplementedException

Tags: azure, uwp, azure-active-directory, windows-community-toolkit

I trying to add the AAD Login Control to my UWP application. I've set the Instance on Startup:

```
        MicrosoftGraphService.Instance.AuthenticationModel = MicrosoftGraphEnums.AuthenticationModel.V2;
        MicrosoftGraphService.Instance.Initialize(ServiceConstants.MSAL_APPLICATION_ID,
                                                  MicrosoftGraphEnums.ServicesToInitialize.UserProfile | MicrosoftGraphEnums.ServicesToInitialize.OneDrive,
                                                  new[] {"User.Read", "Files.ReadWrite" });
```

But when I call `await AADLogin.SignInAsync();` I get a NotImplementedException and a Link to the breaking changes of MSAL v3: https://aka.ms/msal-net-3-breaking-change.

Am I doing something wrong or is version 3 not supported by the control?